# how search with simple_form_for and pg_search gem

Tags: pg-search, simple-form-for

Rails : 5.1.4

I'm trying to search on :immo_type or/and :address

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

def home
    @search = Purchase.find(params[:immo_type]) 
    @purchases = Purchase.where("immo_type ILIKE ?", "%#{@search}%")
end

def index
    @purchases = Purchase.all
    @spurchases = Purchase.search_by_immo_type_and_address('@search')
end
```

end

From the view i used simple_form_for. I don't know how to see how to access the content of params[:immo_type]. When i used rails, i've this message

> Couldn't find Purchase with 'id'=

I can see all my purchases with Purchase.all

```
<%= simple_form_for :immo_type, url: searches_url, method: :get do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :immo_type, params[:immo_type] %>
    <%= f.input :address,  placeholder: 'Town', label: "Where" %>
    <%= f.input :immo_type,  placeholder: 'flat, house', label: "Flat or house" %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Rechercher", class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

Here my models

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
    include PgSearch
    pg_search_scope :search_by_immo_type_and_address, against: [:immo_type, :address]

    belongs_to :user
    has_many :users, :through => :searches
end

class Search < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :leasing
    belongs_to :purchase
end
```

I would like to search from my home.html.erb (root pages) and display the result on my index.html.erb

## SearchesIndex

```
<ul>
  <% @purchases.each do |purchase| %>
    <li><%= link_to purchase.address %></li>
        maison ou appartement : <%= purchase.immo_type %><br>
        prix : entre <%= purchase.price_min %> et <%= purchase.price_max %><br>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, first i need to work with a search controller with the home and index views

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

    def home
        @searches = params[:immo_type]
    end

    def index
        @purchases = Purchase.search_by_immo_type_and_address("#{params[:purchase][:immo_type]}")
    end
end
```

This is my purchase model with Pg_Search gem

```
class Purchase < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :users, :through => :searches

    include PgSearch
    pg_search_scope :search_by_immo_type_and_address, against: [:immo_type]
end
```

And the view with simple_form_for

```
<%= simple_form_for :purchase, url: searches_url, method: :get do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :address %> 
            <%= f.input :immo_type %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Rechercher"%>
<% end %>
```

I hope it can help you !